# How to ignore submodule in "git svn dcommit"?

Tags: git, svn, git-submodules, git-svn, dcommit

'git svn dcommit' fails with the following error

> 6aa885dabeb4f7d78ffcf45f6eb720c60a3e5b50 doesn't exist in the repository at /build/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Editor.pm line 440
>
> Failed to read object 6aa885dabeb4f7d78ffcf45f6eb720c60a3e5b50 at /build/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1017

Found out the issue is because of the submodules later added to the git repo.
Is there a way to ignore submodule commits during `git svn dcommit` without impacting git repo.

**Note:**

Found a solution to rewrite history avoiding the sub-modules with Filter-branch option, but I guess that will tamper the repo which is already on production environment.

Comment: Maybe with `git svn set-tree`, to ignore one commit? (http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Git-svn-dcommit-gt-ignore-one-commit-td6425735.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with the following method:

1. checked out a temporary branch, setting upstream to origin/master
2. did an interactive rebase to remove the submodule checkins
3. executed `git svn dcommit`

It worked!!